# Citations/References using Pandoc (via LaTeX) to export to PDF from Obsidian (markdown): How to have Pandoc just use my text for citations

Tags: markdown, pandoc

The source are markdown files created in Obsidian.

I would like to use Pandoc and LaTeX to automatically cite my sources. I have the bib file all set up, and the LaTeX part too, and directly in a LaTeX editor I can use \cite{Smith2020}to reference a source, and it is then rendered as Smith 2020.

Now I’d just like to be able to include that type of citation in my markdown files so I can then export those to PDF via LaTeX.

Right now when I export this kind of citation it just outputs the citekey itself, with no change.

How can I fix this?

Thank you!

Edit: minimal example:

```
This is a citation \cite{Murray1837Encyclopedia}
This is another citation [@Murray1837Encyclopedia]
```

arguments used for pandoc: `--biblatex`

Edit2: **another example:**

Example .md file:

```
---
bibliography: path/to/.bib/file
csl: https://gist.githubusercontent.com/bwiernik/6b60a0e21ad6b63516a85c305a0d25ad/raw/6e9168cde23fb327d9c483e64cbdfd09e3437851/chicago-author-date-footnotes.csl
---
This is a citation \cite{Murray1837Encyclopedia}
[[@Murray1837Encyclopedia]]This is another citation
```

With the frontmatter as such this, Pandoc can render the second citation [[@blabla]] as Bla bla, p. x. I got this to work a couple hours ago, now it will no longer do it.

Regardless, I would like Pandoc to just ignore citations that look like this `\cite{blabla}` and have LaTeX handle it.

LaTeX can then turn \cite{blabla} into my desired format, namely Bla Bla 2020, 5-10, etc.

How do I get Pandoc to ignore these citations? As it stands, Pandoc removes the command part, and leaves only the citekey, the thing in the brackets.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question correctly, but I believe you either want the `[@Smith2020]` Markdown syntax (lookup "citations" in pandoc's manual) or use the `--biblatex` command line flag. A minimal example would make the question clearer, best with some example Markdown and the current command line used to process it.

Comment: Essentially, I'd kinda just like Pandoc to pass the citations on to LaTeX and then have that convert it to PDF. LaTeX is setup to convert something like `\cite{Smith2020}`to the correct format. But when I try doing this, the output is just the citekey. I've added an example in the post. As I use the Obsidian Pandoc plugin to do the converting, I only have your suggested `biblatex` in the command line.

Comment: Do you set `--bibliography` parameter and have the `--citeproc` flag set?

Comment: I hadn't, but I just tried, and it still doesn't change anything. I tell `--bibliography` the path to my .bib file, correct?
But also, since LaTeX already has all the bibliography info, isn't there a way to have Pandoc pass this stuff on/ignore it? Wouldn't that work?

Comment: I'm still not quite sure what you mean. A more complete example might help.

Comment: I've added another edit. I would just like Pandoc to ignore the citations \cite{abc} so that LaTeX can handle it.

Comment: That should happen automatically. Just making sure that you've seen https://github.com/OliverBalfour/obsidian-pandoc/wiki/Citations-(work-in-progress) ?

Comment: Thanks, I have seen that, and this works when exporting to LibreOffice documents, but not for PDFs. And while that's neat, the problem with that is that the citation style is wrong, so that doesn't work for me. Thank you though!!